# Add reference of caller to in-closure constructor

Tags: javascript, closures, prototype

Ok, I'm creating a constructor object within a closure(to hide it from other scripts that may conflict with it) for another function(this will become clear in a moment). Is there a way to add a reference of the caller function to the in-closed constructor:

```
// this can be located anywhere within a script
(function() {
    function SomeConstructor(param) { this.param = param; }
    SomeConstructor.prototype.doSomething = function(a) { this.param = a; return this; }
    SomeConstructor.prototype.getParam = function() { return this.param }
    // SomeConstructor.prototype.someFunct = ???

    return function someFunct(param) {
        if (param instanceof SomeConstructor) {
            return param;
        }
        else if (param) {
            return new SomeConstructor(param);
        }
    }
}());
```

the reason I need the reference is so I can chain between someFunct and it's constructed objects:

```
someFunct("A").doSomething("a").someFunct("B").doSomething("a").getParam();
```

Please note I need to retain the `instanceof` check, so the following functions as specified:

```
// 1: The inner call creates a new instance of SomeConstructor
// 2: The 2nd(wrapping) call returns the inner calls instance
//        instead of creating a new isntance
var a = someFunct(someFunct("b"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the function to the property of the prototype first and then return this property:

```
(function() {
  function SomeConstructor(param) { this.param = param; }
  SomeConstructor.prototype.doSomething = function(a) { this.param = a; return this; }
  SomeConstructor.prototype.getParam = function() { return this.param }
  SomeConstructor.prototype.someFunct = function someFunct(param) {
     if (param) {
          return new SomeConstructor(param);
     }
   }

   return SomeConstructor.prototype.someFunct; 
 }());
```

Comment: in the `SomeConstructor.prototype.someFunct` will `if (param instanceof SomeConstructor) {...}` continue to process as it should. Im having to change code due to this not working b/c the constructor was being recreated each time someFunct was called which is where this question originates.

Comment: Do you mean `this instanceof SomeConstructor` ?

Comment: no. `someFunct(new someFunct("a"))`, the first call should create a new instance of `SomeConstructor`, with the wrapping call, would `if (param instanceof SomeConstructor){...}` evaluate to true if it was inside the `someFunct` function

Comment: That seems to work when I try it. The wrapping call correctly sees it as an instance of `SomeConstructor` and returns it instead of creating a new object. Does it not work for you?

Comment: I didn't test before asking. Thought you might have known off hand. Thank you, will test to make sure. If it works will upvote and accept.